# Quarto fig-cap with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, quarto

I'm using `Quarto` and trying to display a caption below a `plotly` graph:

````
```{r}
#| fig-cap: "*Caption here"
#| column: page-inset-right

library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
fig
```
````

Unfortunately, the caption does not display in the rendered document. I thought `fig-cap` only works for static graphics, but then I saw [this Posit's example](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/computations/text-editor.html#multiple-figures) where they seem to be able to use `fig-cap` with plotly graphs.

How can I add a caption below a plotly graph in Quarto under R?

Comment: which version of knitr are you using ? It is possibly a bug introduced by dev version of knitr

Comment: Yes, it turns out it was the specific development version of `knitr` I was using.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a `label` to display the figure caption like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

Here is your @fig-plotly

```{r}
#| label: fig-plotly
#| fig-cap: "*Caption here"
#| column: page-inset-right
#| echo: false
#| message: false

library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
fig
```
````

Output:

[image]

---

Here similarly but without referencing in your text:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-plotly
#| fig-cap: "*Caption here"
#| column: page-inset-right
#| echo: false
#| message: false

library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
fig
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I still don't get the caption. I tried the reprex exactly as you have it. Also tried a different browser. `plotly` version ‘4.10.1’; `quarto` version ‘1.2’, R R version 4.2.2; Rstudio 2023.03.1 Build 409. Everything works for regular `ggplot` graphs.

Comment: Hi @ThomasSpeidel, I am using R version 4.2.3; Quarto 1.3.276 (latest version); plotly 4.10.1.9000; I would highly recommend you updating your [quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/download/).

Comment: This is strange: I have updated R, Quarto, and all packages and still no caption. I'm puzzled.

Comment: To add to this, I just rerun the same reprex on another machine with the same version of everything except different OS (Linux) and the caption are correctly placed. Mystery thickens.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a pointer on the [RStudio community site](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-generate-captions-with-a-plotly-graph/163208/3), I discovered the problem lies in the `knitr` version.  With the development version ‘1.42.3’ (which is what I was using), captions are **not** rendered underneath a `plotly` graph. With either the stable version and the developmental 1.42.5, this is no longer an issue.